# Java: How to read a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io, text-files

I want to read a text file containing space separated values. Values are integers.
How can I read it and put it in an array list?

Here is an example of contents of the text file:

```
1 62 4 55 5 6 77
```

I want to have it in an arraylist as `[1, 62, 4, 55, 5, 6, 77]`. How can I do it in Java?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can use [`Files#readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) to get all lines of a text file into a `List<String>`.

```
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))) {
    // ...
}
```

Tutorial: [Basic I/O > File I/O > Reading, Writing and Creating text files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

---

You can use [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split a `String` in parts based on a regular expression.

```
for (String part : line.split("\\s+")) {
    // ...
}
```

Tutorial: [Numbers and Strings > Strings > Manipulating Characters in a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html)

---

You can use [`Integer#valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert a `String` into an `Integer`.

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(part);
```

Tutorial: [Numbers and Strings > Strings > Converting between Numbers and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html)

---

You can use [`List#add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) to add an element to a `List`.

```
numbers.add(i);
```

Tutorial: [Interfaces > The List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

---

So, in a nutshell (assuming that the file doesn't have empty lines nor trailing/leading whitespace).

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))) {
    for (String part : line.split("\\s+")) {
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(part);
        numbers.add(i);
    }
}
```

---

If you happen to be at Java 8 already, then you can even use [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for this, starting with [`Files#lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-).

```
List<Integer> numbers = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/test.txt"))
    .map(line -> line.split("\\s+")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .map(Integer::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Tutorial: [Processing data with Java 8 streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html)

Comment: Note that there are better ways to do this in Java 7 and 8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file

Answer (score 34):

Java 1.5 introduced the [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for handling input from file and streams.

It is used for getting integers from a file and would look something like this:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("c:\\file.txt"));
while (fileScanner.hasNextInt()){
   integers.add(fileScanner.nextInt());
}
```

Check the API though. There are many more options for dealing with different types of input sources, differing delimiters, and differing data types.

Comment: this is by far easier to remember than the buffered, io, reader combination

Answer (score 18):

This example code shows you how to read file in Java.

```
import java.io.*;

/**
 * This example code shows you how to read file in Java
 *
 * IN MY CASE RAILWAY IS MY TEXT FILE WHICH I WANT TO DISPLAY YOU CHANGE WITH YOUR   OWN      
 */

 public class ReadFileExample 
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       System.out.println("Reading File from Java code");
       //Name of the file
       String fileName="RAILWAY.txt";
       try{

          //Create object of FileReader
          FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

          //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
          BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

          //Variable to hold the one line data
          String line;

          // Read file line by line and print on the console
          while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
          //Close the buffer reader
          bufferReader.close();
       }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());                      
       }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

Look at this example, and try to do your own:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String string = "";
        String file = "textFile.txt";

        // Reading
        try{
            InputStream ips = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                string += line + "\n";
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        // Writing
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
            PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter (bw);
                fileOut.println (string+"\n test of read and write !!");
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("the file " + file + " is created!");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here's what I'd probably do in a real project, where I'm already using all my favourite libraries (in this case [**Guava**](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), formerly known as *Google Collections*).

```
String text = Files.toString(new File("textfile.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList();
for (String s : text.split("\\s")) {
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
```

Benefit: Not much own code to maintain (contrast with e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java/2790331#2790331)). *Edit*: Although it is worth noting that in this case [tschaible's Scanner solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java/2788178#2788178) doesn't have any more code!

Drawback: you obviously may not want to add new library dependencies just for this. <sup>(Then again, you'd be silly not to make use of Guava in your projects. ;-)</sup>

Comment: Of course one could also use transform() & a Function from Google Collections instead of the loop, but IMHO that would be less readable and not even shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) (IO and Lang) for simple/common things like this.

Imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
```

Code:

```
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("path/to/your/file.txt"));
String[] array = ArrayUtils.toArray(contents.split(" "));
```

Done.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 7 to read files with NIO.2

Import these packages:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

This is the process to read a file:

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Java\\file.txt");

if(Files.exists(file) && Files.isReadable(file)) {

    try {
        // File reader
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, Charset.defaultCharset());

        String line;
        // read each line
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            // tokenize each number
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                // parse each integer in file
                int element = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To read all lines of a file at once:

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Java\\file.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far given involve reading the file line by line, taking the line in as a `String`, and then processing the `String`.

There is no question that this is the easiest approach to understand, and if the file is fairly short (say, tens of thousands of lines), it'll also be acceptable in terms of efficiency. **But if the file is long**, it's a very inefficient way to do it, for two reasons:

1. Every character gets processed twice, once in constructing the `String`, and once in processing it.
2. The garbage collector will not be your friend if there are lots of lines in the file. You're constructing a new `String` for each line, and then throwing it away when you move to the next line. The garbage collector will eventually have to dispose of all these `String` objects that you don't want any more. Someone's got to clean up after you.

If you care about speed, you are much better off reading a block of data and then processing it byte by byte rather than line by line. Every time you come to the end of a number, you add it to the `List` you're building.

It will come out something like this:

```
private List<Integer> readIntegers(File file) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    byte buf[] = new byte[16 * 1024];
    final FileChannel ch = raf.getChannel();
    int fileLength = (int) ch.size();
    final MappedByteBuffer mb = ch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,
            fileLength);
    int acc = 0;
    while (mb.hasRemaining()) {
        int len = Math.min(mb.remaining(), buf.length);
        mb.get(buf, 0, len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if ((buf[i] >= 48) && (buf[i] <= 57))
                acc = acc * 10 + buf[i] - 48;
            else {
                result.add(acc);
                acc = 0;
            }
    }
    ch.close();
    raf.close();
    return result;
}
```

The code above assumes that this is ASCII (though it could be easily tweaked for other encodings), and that anything that isn't a digit (in particular, a space or a newline) represents a boundary between digits. It also assumes that the file ends with a non-digit (in practice, that the last line ends with a newline), though, again, it could be tweaked to deal with the case where it doesn't.

It's **much, much faster** than any of the `String`-based approaches also given as answers to this question. There is a detailed investigation of a very similar issue [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606833/fastest-way-to-sum-integers-in-text-file). You'll see there that there's the possibility of improving it still further if you want to go down the multi-threaded line.

Answer (score 0):

read the file and then do whatever you want 
java8
Files.lines(Paths.get("c://lines.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());