# Java Convert from .bin file to .txt loading

Tags: java

How would I go about changing this from loading .bin to .txt. I would like the information on the .txt file be put into the hashmap just like .bin file.

```
    public static int currency;
    public HashMap<Integer, Shop> cars = new HashMap<Integer, Car>();    
public void load() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                RandomAccessFile carFile = new RandomAccessFile("data/cars.bin", "r");
                int carsAmt = carFile.readShort();
                for (int carId = 0; carId < carAmt; carId++) {
                    int carId = carFile.readShort();
                    int currency = carFile.readShort();
                    int[] cars = new int[carFile.readByte()];
                    int[] amounts = new int[cars.length];
                    boolean isTruck = carFile.read() == 1;
                    for (int carData = 0; carData < cars.length; carData++) {
                        cars[carData] = carFile.readShort();
                        amounts[carData] = carFile.readInt();
                    }
                    cars.put(carId, new Car(carId, currency, isTruck, cars, amounts, true));
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Loaded " + cars.size() + " Cars");
        }
```

Comment: RandomAccessFile can read any file.

Comment: Why can't you change `"data/cars.bin"` to `"data/cars.txt"`?

Answer (score 2):

`bin` and `txt` are just parts of the name. However, by convention, a `txt` file contains data formatted using one of many **character encodings**. Common encodings are UTF-8 and the extensions of ASCII. An "encoding" is just a mapping of a sequence of bytes to a character. For example, in UTF-8, `a` maps to the 8 bit sequence `01100001` (`61` in hexadecimal). Realistically, all files are stored as a series of `0`s and `1`s, but `txt` files usually only store sequences according to their encoding. By contrast, a `bin` file would contain data stored in a "binary" format; that is, the data in them does not match any kind of text encoding. In your case, the `bin` file just contains a set of numbers stored as their binary representations (which is a sequence of bits or 0s and 1s).

The answer to your question is that you're going to have to rewrite this block of code. Since you now want to read a text file instead of using the binary values directly, you'll need a reader that can decode your `txt` file into `String`s, and then you'll also need to turn those `String`s into numeric values. (This step is called "parsing".)

You **will** need to know the encoding of your `txt` file to be able to read it correctly. `RandomAccessFile` has a method to read UTF-8 encoding text, but if it's in another encoding, you'll need to look elsewhere. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788114/1394393) for some information on using `BufferedReader`. You may also find the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class useful. `Scanner` can parse the values for you as it reads them in.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote this 100-fold. Excellent answer.