# Reading data from .txt file in java

Tags: java

I have a .txt file in folder conf which contains data as

```
path = "F://Files//Report.txt" 

name="Henry"

status="1"
```

I want to read the path of this file in java, and to store that path in another variable in Java.  How can I do this?  I am new to Java.

Comment: I have searched for this but got methods to read the whole file i want to read only that particular path from that file

Comment: you can read the first line, or just read the file and do some fancy String work to get just the path.

Comment: you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: Thanks to all target achieved ...

Answer (score 5):

Check out [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). The [`Properties.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) method has the ability to load a "key=value" formatted file into a map of keys -> values.

You can then access the data like `theProperties.getProperty("path")`.

Note that you will have to trim leading/trailing double quotes off of the values if the file contains double quotes. For your situation, it is *probably* sufficient to simply remove all quotes, but it depends on your requirements.

Example: Loading the file:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"));
String path = p.getProperty("path");
```

Example: Removing the double quotes (`path` will contain, literally, `"F://Files//Report.txt"` since that's what it is in the file):

```
path = path.replace("\"", "");
```

Note that `getProperty()` returns `null` if the property is not found, so you will want to prepare for that:

```
String path = p.getProperty("path");
if (path != null)
    path = path.replace("\"", "");
```

Also note that this is a very naive way to remove double quotes (it will mercilessly remove *all* double quotes, not just ones at the beginning or end) but is probably sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Not able to figure out this i am new to files in java so can you please post some piece of code for this problem ..I'll be highly thankful to you.

Comment: @AyushJain Is that better? Bhushan's answer also has a good example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use property file to simplify your task:

Set values in property file at root folder of your project:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("my.properties");
prop.setProperty("path ", "F://Files//Report.txt");
prop.setProperty("name", "Henry");
prop.setProperty("status", "1");
prop.store(output, null);
```

Read values from property file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("my.properties");
prop.load(fis);
String path = prop.getProperty("path");
String name = prop.getProperty("name");
String status = prop.getProperty("status");
```

**Update**

If you want to use only text file as you mentioned in comments you can try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://test.txt"));
String path="";
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    path = line;
    path = path.substring(path.indexOf("\""));//get the string after the first occurrence of double quote
    path = path.replace("\"", "").trim();//remove double quotes from string
    break;//read only first line to get path
}
System.out.println(path);
```

Output:

```
F://Files//Report.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this but is there a way to do the same with .txt files as i have some other operations too to perform on same file.

Comment: @Bhushan You don't need (or want) to "escape" forward slashes. `"/"` is fine, `"\\"` would be necessary. `"//"` is literally two /'s (although all platforms that I know of collapse consecutive path separators into one, so in the end it's not an issue).

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for the note, and +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Properties` for reading key=value pairs. You can refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Note : [Here](http://www.javavids.com/video/how-to-easily-read-data-from-properties-file-in-java.html) is a good tutorial to start with.