# How do I put a file with full names into an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a file in the project in netbeans called "input.txt" which has a list of names like the following:

```
John Doe
Magnus Carlsen
Mikhail Tal
Bobby Fischer
```

I created an arraylist with:

```
ArrayList <String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to add in the arraylist names. I want the value at [0] to be "John Doe" and the value at [1] to be "Magnus Carlsen" and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read a tutorial on Java IO.

Comment: you might want to read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java

; and the rest is just `names.add(..)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8

```
List<String> names = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/names/file.txt"));
```

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

### Java 7

```
List<String> names = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/path/To/Your/File.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware links were discouraged

Comment: Links aren't discouraged. *Link-only answers* are discouraged. Put the link there, but elaborate on it in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow trivial:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        names.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("My list: " + names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filePath"));
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

while (s.hasNext()){
    names.add(s.nextLine());
}

s.close()
```

Comment: What does `next()` do?

Comment: [I don't think it does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it may need `.useDelimiter("\n")` but I'm pretty sure it does that by default. Haven't checked this yet but off the top of my head it seems ok

Comment: The default is whitespace. So a space between words will be considered the end of a token. This won't read a full line. Use `nextLine()` for that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, I'll take your word on that. Updated my answer, cheers

Comment: Don't forget to also switch hasNext for hasNextLine. Don't take my word for it, you should try it when you have a chance.