# Reading from a textfile to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I am supposed to read a few lines from a textfile and then store them in an arraylist.
What is the best way to do such a thing?
I must later be able to check each individual char.

Comment: 1. read the file line by line, 2. put each line into an array list, 3. enjoy - did you try that already?

Comment: The best approach is writing code.

Comment: Come on... do a little research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java

Comment: You cannot expect people here to do your homework.

Comment: You can try to use a `Scanner` to read the file line by line, and store them in an `ArrayList` as you read them. Is you use java 7 or 8, you can use `Files.readAllLines()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned that I have already written the scanner thing, I am just unfamiliar with arraylist and didn't find what I was looking for when I googled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the simple snippet to do your work :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseFile
    {            
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scanner = null;
            ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
               scanner= new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    store.add(scanner.next());             
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();            
            }
            finally{
                scanner.close();
            }

            for (String item : store) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Come on. This _looks like_ Java, but does not even compile! Also, resource management is bad, i.e. you need to close the Scanner in a finally block. Finally, what do you expect to see in that System.out line at the end? The lines added to the ArrayList?! No way ...

Comment: I said its snippet which could do it. I didnt intend to spoon feed. I just wanted to give the direction.

Comment: Sure, NP. Sorry for sounding harsh.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache commons io `List lines = FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Files.readAllLines(Path path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

```
Path path = //...
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

But using this approach, you'll have 2 lists in memory twice for a short time (i.e. during the execution of the `ArrayList` constructor).

If you don't need a modifiable list and don't need the list's type to be a `ArrayList`

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

works too, of course.

In **java 8** you can of course use `Stream`s too:

```
final ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(path)) {
    lineStream.forEach(lines::add);
}
```

This way the lines are added to the list directly after they are read.

Comment: Good pointer! While Files is Java 7, readAllLines(Path) is only in Java 8, though ... need to use readAllLines(Path,CharSet) for Java 7...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 FileReader in = null;
    try
    {
        in = new FileReader("C:/Test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();


        String s = br.readLine();
        while (s != null)
        {
            lines.add(s);
            s = br.readLine();

        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Read.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```