# Getting a random word from a string array text file

Tags: java, arrays, class, random

```
 package hangman;

 import java.util.Random;

 public class Dictionary {

     int NUMBER_OF_WORDS = 81452;
     public static String FILE_NAME = "dictionaryCleaned.txt";
     private String[] dictionary = new String[NUMBER_OF_WORDS];

     public string getRandomWord() {
          Random rand = new Random();

          return randWord;
     }

 }
```

I am trying randomly generate a word from the array that contains the text file "dictionaryCleaned.txt" so that I can return the random word to my main method in a separate class. I feel like there could be something wrong with the array, as it does not appear to have the text file loaded into the empty array spaces. I need to return a word from "dictionary", but it is eluding me.

Thank you

Comment: is there a code where you load the contents of the text file into the array or you wait it to happen magically?

Comment: Check for a "File to String Array" topic first. Then check for a "Java Random" tutorial. Then edit your question. Then ask us to write comments or answers again.

Comment: You haven't popluated the dictionary with any data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java getRandomWord() should return a String not string. The correct way to use random is answered below.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you left out the file reading part,

I would keep the Random() as instance variable in your Dictionary here.

```
 private final Random random = new Random();
```

And:

```
 public String getRandomWord() {
      return dictionary[random.nextInt(dictionary.length)];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning a random word from your dictionnary is easy:

```
public String getRandomWord() {
     final Random rand = new Random();

     return dictionary[rand.nextInt(dictionary.length)];
}
```

But you still have to write the code to load your file in your dictionnary.

Answer (score 0):

considering your **dictionary** reference has all the data loaded from the dictionary file, then to load random string you can use

```
String randomValue = dictionary[new Random().nextInt(dictionary.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getRandomWord` method should be:

```
public String getRandomWord() {
   Random rand = new Random();
   int index = rand.nextInt(dictionary.length);
   String randWord= dictionary[index];

   return randWord;
 }
```

Comment: The person who down voted this, will you mind explaining, that will help me as well as others.

Answer (score 0):

First you must load your words to the array. Then only you can get a random word from your word array.

so your code should be like
package hangman;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dictionary {
     int NUMBER_OF_WORDS = 81452;
     public static String FILE_NAME = "dictionaryCleaned.txt";
     private String[] dictionary = new String[NUMBER_OF_WORDS];

     public void loadWordList(String fileName){
          // write your logic to read the file and load them into the dictionary array
     }

     public String getRandomWord() {
          Random rand = new Random();
          return dictionary[rand.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_WORDS)];
     }
 }
```