# How to import a file into multiple ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Java beginner here, please be patient. So I need to import a txt file that looks like this

A

Germany

India

B

Vietnam

China

and the program will need to compare the country that the user typed then determine whether it belongs to group A or B and return the group. I have been told to use `ArrayList`. At the moment my code looks like

```
public class regionCountry
{
   public String region;
   public ArrayList <String> countryList;
} 

public class destination
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      ArrayList<regionCountry> rc = new ArrayList<regionCountry>;
   }
}
```

but I still have no idea what to do. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read documentation on reading text files? Start with that and show some code on how far you get, then we will help you.

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java) will get you started.

Comment: If you're talking about the scanner and new File() then yes. It looks something like Scanner c = new Scanner(new File("c:/myfile.txt")); My question is how to determine if the country belongs to the specific group as there are multiple countries in one group.

Comment: Your naming convention for naming classes is wrong. Use Capitalized. Your code to next reader should be good read.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow following steps.

```
1. Read your file (You can use Scanner)
2. Split data and store them in a `ArrayList`.
```

Now let's try to work on these.

How to read a file?

```
 File file=new File("yourFilePath");
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
      // now you can get content of file from here.
 }
```

Then split content and create an instance of your object set region and add country list.

Note:

Use proper naming conversion. change `regionCountry` to `RegionCountry`. Class name should start with capital letter.

Make all variables private and add public getters and setters.

Edit: for your comment. How to determine the group and country?

```
 File file=new File("/home/ruchira/Test.txt");
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
 RegionCountry regionCountry = null;
 List<RegionCountry> regionCountryList=new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> groupList=new ArrayList<>();
 groupList.add("A");
 groupList.add("B");
 List<String> countryList = null;
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line=scanner.nextLine();
    if(!"".equals(line)){
        if(groupList.contains(line.trim())){
         if(regionCountry!=null&&groupList.contains(regionCountry.getRegion())){
             regionCountryList.add(regionCountry);
           }
          regionCountry=new RegionCountry();
          regionCountry.setRegion(line);
          countryList=new ArrayList<>();
          }else {
          countryList.add(line);    // those will never be null in this logic
          regionCountry.setCountryList(countryList);
         }
       }
   }
  regionCountryList.add(regionCountry);// last group you have to take from here.
  System.out.println(regionCountryList);
```

Out put: (I have override `toString()` in `RegionCountry` )

> [RegionCountry{region='A', countryList=[Germany, India]},
>   RegionCountry{region='B', countryList=[Vietnam, China]}]