# over write file in java

Tags: java, file, io

possible duplicate : [Java: How to read a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java)

this is my code:

```
this.fileMetaDataPrintWriter = 
new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName), false));
```

and in other method

```
fileMetaDataPrintWriter.write(somedata);
```

these both methods are called in a thread and the filehandle closed when thread exits.

Still my file is **appended and not overwritten**.

what is the mistake?

Comment: This code does not append to the file. Either this isn't the real code or you have other code that does append to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified that the following code snippet written directly in `main` method is overwriting the file contents. Perhaps it is some other interaction in code that is causing a different behavior for you? Test this snippet and verify if overwrite works correctly

```
PrintWriter fileMetaDataPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("appendtest.txt"), false), true);
fileMetaDataPrintWriter.write("This replaces contents of appendtest.txt");
fileMetaDataPrintWriter.close();
```

Comment: The `flush()` is redundant before `close().`

Comment: Autoflush has nothing to do with it. `flush()` is *always* redundant before `close().`

Comment: I understand, I would normally use `try-with-resources` construct or put the `close()` in a finally block. Auto `flush()` is my choice if I want to tail the file while it's being written