# What is the opposite of PrintWriter class?

Tags: java, file, class, file-io, io

There is a class in Java called the PrintWriter where it can output the string into a file, which I found very easy to use since I only want to print strings. But now I want to take this file Strings and replace couple of words via code, how can I achieve that? is there any PrintReader class or similar?

Comment: [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), use it from the view of `BufferedReader`

Comment: [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)? Your question isn't entirely clear. Not that you cannot replace words in a file without writing a new file with the replacements and then replacing the file. Well, you can - but it's really quite tricky.

Comment: @NajiKadri DontPrintReader? Just kidding. The java doc is your friend. [DontBeLazy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 4):

For smaller files you can read all and write all using [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Data/text.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Files.write(lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The above uses the Path class that is the more general successor of File.

Also a characterset is specified, here UTF-8, so you can combine all kinds of Unicode scripts, special symbols.

For Windows NotePad to recognize UTF-8 you can add a BOM as first character of the file (zero-width space):

```
lines.put(0, "\uFEFF", lines.get(0));
```

(With a bit more care of course.)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything called PrintReader. The BufferedReader class should pretty much do what you need.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html). Since you're trying to read a file, maybe you should take a look at [reading-a-text-file-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java).