# Read and calculate sum of integers from a file in Java

Tags: java, io, java-io

Assume I have a simple text file **Simple.txt** which contains data like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

or

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

how to read this file and print the sum of the integers using Java?

Comment: Use `Scanner`. Iterate over your data `while` it `hasNextInt()` and get that `nextInt()`.

Comment: Google around a 'scanner' and 'nextint'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java and then loop through the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SumNumbers {

public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
        int sum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            sum += scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Sum:"+sum); 
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

EDIT: If you want to catch improper inputs in the file, you can change while loop as follows

```
         while (scanner.hasNext()){
            int num = 0;
            try{
                num = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            }catch(NumberFormatException ne){

            }
            sum += num;
        }
```

Comment: No, please don't use try-catch to handle incorrect input types. Scanner allows us to use `hasNextTYPE` so lets use it instead. In case of incorrect type simply invoke `has...` and consume that incorrect value with `next` or `nextLine` (if we want to consume all values in line after incorrect one).

Comment: You should at least check the length of `args` before attempting to access its elements; don't rely on the user supplying the right command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
    {
        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File("Simple.txt"));

        filereader(textfile);
}   


   static void filereader(Scanner textfile)     
{         
    int i = 0;         
    int sum = 0;          
    while(textfile.hasNextLine())         
    {       
        int nextInt = textfile.nextInt();          

        System.out.println(nextInt);             
        sum = sum + nextInt;
        i++;         
    }     
}
```

Comment: Why while(i <= 4) ?  I wanted to read upto the end of the file not on any specific condition.

Comment: you have to use `while(textfile.hasNextLine())`

Comment: so would you please up vote, and accept my answer.