# Passing a file into a program using Eclipse

Tags: java

Ok so this may be a dumb question, but how do I pass a text file into my java program and likewise have a method which reads over it? I know I need to use a scanner. But I have unsuccessfully gotten the program to even recognize the text file. Any ideas?

Comment: You _could_ pass an entire text file to a Java program, but a more typical usage would be to pass the _filename_ instead.  If you show us some code, maybe we can give you better pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to one way to do it, try googling it also if this doesn't help.
[Java: How to read a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/reading-a-text-file-in-java)

This is a pretty common thing in java and should have many examples online.

You could also use a reader of some sort such as a bufferedReader https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html