# Setting text for text view

Tags: android

I am creating one tutorial and for that i want to set text for text view. I know we can set text by textView.setText("your stuff") but my text is too large and it looks awkward in java file. So is there any other efficient way of doing it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: place it inside ScrollView

Comment: that ok. but i don't want to put that large text in java file. I don't know if there is any other way of doing it?

Comment: How about String Resources? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: thank you it was helpful

Answer (score 4):

Place it in string resources

```
<string name="long_string">
  Very long string
</string>
```

Access it in java

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text);
textView.setText(R.string.long_string);
```

You can check [CHARACTERS TO ESCAPE IN XML DOCUMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) incase you have them in text content

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have already suggested putting it in a string resource. As an alternative to that, you can also put it under `res/raw` and read it like a regular text file.

Example:

**res/raw/looooong.txt**

> This is some looooooooooooooooooooooooong text.
>   You can even put them in separate lines.
>   Just make sure to handle reading the newline characters.

**TextView**

```
textView.setText(readRawResource(context, R.raw.looooong));
```

**readRawResource**

```
private String readRawResource(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText(" AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
```

### OR

Read it from a file like this

```
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt")))
{
  // ...
}
```

Save the output in a string, Then just show it using `textView.setText("x");`

for more information , read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788080/java-how-to-read-a-text-file)

### EDIT

You will need to learn about `ScrollView` or `HorizontalScrollView` if your text is more than the size of the screen. Also use [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) , don't forget to set a string ID for the textView.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understood but if its the length in the file what bothers you you can set your string in the strings resource file
    res/values/string.xml
This way: 
     your stuf 
 Then in your Code set the string as follows:
   textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.my_string));